Compare two consecutive rows in datastage and throw the rows that doesn't meet a condition
I'm reading a file using a sequential file in Datastage and I'm doing some transformation in the data using a transformer, I want to compare the current row with the previous row, to check a value of a column. If the condition is OK then I will display the two rows else I will reject the both lines
An example of the input file :
ID.    MESSAGE
50     1-line1
50     1-line2
40     2-line1
40.    2-line2
50.    3-line1
50.    3-line2
Two consécutives rows have the same ID , and if the column message of a row is 1-line1 the second row must be 1-line2 , if so we will load the both rows ,if not the both rows will be rejected and the process continue to 2-line1 and 2-line2 to do the same process
How can i implement this scenario in datastage,I'm already using the variable but it's not working
Any help ? Thanks in advance.
I tried the variable in transformer to compare row by row but i can't throw the both or load the both rows.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your scenario can be solved within a transformer using a loop.
Check out the transformer loop decumentation.
If you want to access the data of a previous row you have to be aware of the top down processing of the variables. If i.e. the top most stage variable (or loop variable) references a later one - the later one will still have the data from the previous row.
As your logic involved both rows you have to use a loop.
With SaveInputRecord() you can store the first row until you have checked the second for your logic.
Also check out loop variable examples
Please note that for this case the transformer needs a sorted input.
